# Install SmoothDraw on Ubuntu

Tags: wine, software-installation

I want to install `SmoothDraw` in Ubuntu so that I can make a few drawings and stuff. I have installed `WINE` and installed `SmoothDraw` however, it does not start when I double click on its icon (On the desktop).

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
**Please help me run it**

Terminal output

```
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"configSections" in state 1
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"sectionGroup" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"section" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"userSettings" in state 1
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"SmoothDraw.Properties.Settings" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
wine: Install Mono for Windows to run .NET 2.0 applications.
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the output of `wine <path to SmoothDraw binary>`?

Comment: @Jobin I do not know how to do that ! :) Please tell me how to.

Comment: Open a terminal using Ctrl+Alt+t and then type `wine ~/Desktop/SmoothDraw.exe`.

Comment: @Jobin here i s the output http://pastebin.com/JgazkPt2

Comment: Please edit your question with the output.

Answer (score 1):

I installed SmoothDraw 4.0.5 with PlayOnLinux on Arch Linux (I know this is exclusively an Ubuntu forum but it should work the same for the most part). I believe I installed the `dotnet40` or `dotnet45` library during the installation (I definitely installed one of them, if not `dotnet45` then I installed it afterwards by going into Settings > Install Components). It should theoretically work with simply `dotnet40` but I did not one of the required libraries to be specifically that. I also tried installing `mono` but noticed something in the logs of it getting removed or something, though it is still installed on my system according to `pacman` (the default Arch Linux package manager), so I do not believe it is needed. But something that is needed for sure is to configure Wine so that the Windows version is set to "Windows 7". It was set to Windows 3.1 by default I think.

The colors are a little messed up. Choosing a color and/or tool may be a bit cumbersome, but I'm sure that with enough clicking around you can find your way. Also it may be hard to select different colors quickly, like Sal Khan of Khan Academy does in his videos. You can see a screenshot here.

[image: screenshot]

Also regarding `@An SO User`'s question regarding a Linux alternative (in the form of a comment on `@jobin`'s answer), I find that the [Paintbrush tool in GIMP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PkqY.png) is quite similar to the [Pen tool in SmoothDraw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dclu9.png).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need to install mono for .net applications of Windows to run in Ubuntu. To install mono, open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and then type:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

Comment: Still the same :(

Comment: @LittleChild: Modified the package name.

Comment: Ok, I was in  process of downloading `mono-develop`and now I cancelled it since you changed the package name. Where did those files go ? Are they still on my disc ?

Comment: @LittleChild: They will be removed if they are not needed anymore.

Comment: Where is a good place to start learning the terminal commands systematically (from ground-up rather than random commands) ?

Comment: @LittleChild: Here is a related question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/337300/are-there-any-games-which-can-train-people-to-learn-terminal-commands If this is not what you were looking for, post a question for this(?) Btw, was the issue resolved?

Comment: I still get the same error and I do not know why. Did the `mono` package install properly ? How do I check that ?

Comment: nevermind. Is there a Linux alternative of SmoothDraw you are aware of ?

Comment: @LittleChild: Nopes, sorry!